# Reading environment variables from .env file in pythonanywhere.com

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

SOLVED: I was editing the wrong WISGI file. I didn't realize there was 2 separate WISGI files. Issue resolved. Thank you Forcebru for your help.

I wrote an article detailing the process of [How to Deploy Django on PytonAnywhere](https://engineertodeveloper.com/deploy-a-django-project-to-pythonanywhere/). Hopefully, that helps some people avoid the pitfalls I made.

I am trying to set environment variables using a .env file in pythonanywhere.com but I keep getting an error saying my SECRET_KEY is empty so my environment variables aren't being set.

I'm following the article from pythonanywhere.com

link: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/my-project-dir')  # adjust as appropriate
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))
```

I don't quite understand the 3rd line. In the terminal, I cd into the project folder and run the pwd command to get the path. I'm not sure what part I am supposed to include for the argument for `os.path.expanduser('~/my-project-dir')`.

Following the section for the bash console in the article, I had no trouble accessing my environment variables. So I think I am using the correct working project directory. I was able to echo to the console.

Here's my WISGI file:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/bogalusa-church')
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'bogalusa_church.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The working directory I used for setting up the variables for the bash terminal is the same one I am using here.

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `cat ~/bogalusa-church/.env` in the console?

Comment: It outputs all the key value pairs in the .env file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure what part I am supposed to include

The part after your home directory. If you have `/Users/forcebru/test`, then the argument will be `~/test` because the tilde stands for your home directory (`/Users/forcebru`).

If you're not sure what your home directory is, just do this:

```
project_folder = <output of `pwd` after `cd` to project dir>
```

Comment: I think I am in the working directory now. Whenever I added the environment variables to my bash terminal in the next part of the article. I was able to echo out my environment variables in the terminal. So I'm confident I added the correct directory. I keep getting the error saying that the SECRET_KEY cant be empty.

Answer (score 1):

the part of the home directory

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/AOJCM/')  # adjust as appropriate thats my directory
load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))
```

then settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
```

**note:
.env should contain all your keys without spaces in them between the equal sign = **

```
export SECRET_KEY='djfjksdhfhsjfhjsdjfJjsKrandomsecretkey'
```